# Get external storage parent folder on android

Tags: android, android-file

I've an application on the Play Store, and a user sent me a bug report saying that on his device the external sdcard is not listed in the external storage device list, though is mounted and accessible at `/mnt/external_sd`

I have a dialog listing folders and start directory is `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.
After some clicks to get to the parent folder, the `/storage` folder is reached and `getParent()` returns null. 
Which starting folder should I set to have access to the full storage structure?

**EDIT:**
As a workaround I am adding in my app preference the ability to choose if the storage root directory should be `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` or hardcoded `/mnt`.

Comment/answer if there are best alternatives.

Comment: do you know which version android he has?

Comment: There is a bug on Samsung devices, once you upgrade to the newer version (Forgive me I forgot the details) you run into this SD card issue.

Comment: I am facing same problem.right i'm using solution "/mnt" for getting root dir.but when i'm saving any file in external sdcard.its creating same path/folder starts from mnt in internal sdcard.

Comment: @blackbelt user both tried on Samsung Galaxy S4 (android 4.3) and Archos Gamepad 2 (android 4.2.2)

Answer (score 0):

> Get external storage parent folder on android

By *external storage*, I am assuming that you meant micro SD card storage.

> external sdcard is not listed in the external storage device list,
>   though is mounted and accessible at `/mnt/external_sd`

You cannot access SD storage by using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` method.

Before **API level 19**, there was **no official way** to store in SD card. But, many could do it using unofficial APIs.

Officially, one method was introduced in `Context` class in API level 19 (Android version 4.4 - Kitkat).

```
File[] getExternalFilesDirs (String type)
```

> It returns absolute paths to application-specific directories on all
>   shared/external storage devices where the application can place
>   persistent files it owns. These files are internal to the application,
>   and not typically visible to the user as media.

That means, it will return paths to both Micro SD card and Internal memory. Generally, **second returned path** would be storage path of micro SD card.

The Internal and External Storage **terminology** according to Google/[official Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) is **quite different** from what we think.